# Why is my data not passing between View Controllers using closure?

Tags: swift

I am trying to pass data receive from a network call to another view controller when user has clicked on a button. When making printing on the FirstVC, data is in, but when printing the result in the SecondVC, there is no more value. I don' t want to use delegate but closure instead.
Also, when trying to retain the memory cycle, an error appear...

```
class APIsRuler {
    static var oneRecipeFound: ((OneRecipeSearch) -> ())?
}

class FirstVC: UIViewController {
    func cellIsClicked(index: Int) {
        APIsRuler.shared.getRecipe(from: recipeID) { (success, oneRecipe) in
            if success, let oneRecipe = oneRecipe {
                APIsRuler.oneRecipeFound?(oneRecipe)
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecondVC", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}

Class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        APIsRuler.oneRecipeFound = { result in
            print(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: APIsRuler.oneRecipeFound = { result in
      print(result)
    } . PUT this code into viewWillAppear method... I hope it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this in SecondVC

```
APIsRuler.oneRecipeFound = { result in
  print(result)
}
```

and this in first

```
APIsRuler.oneRecipeFound?(oneRecipe)
```

have no inner communications , you need to read your data directly from the shared class in the secondVc after the segue  or send it in

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecondVC", sender: <#Herererere#>)
```

and implement `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 0):

Let’s think about the order in which things are happening:

```
class APIsRuler {
    static var oneRecipeFound: ((OneRecipeSearch) -> ())? // 1
}

class FirstVC: UIViewController {
    func cellIsClicked(index: Int) {
        APIsRuler.shared.getRecipe(from: recipeID) { (success, oneRecipe) in
            if success, let oneRecipe = oneRecipe {
                APIsRuler.oneRecipeFound?(oneRecipe) // 2
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecondVC", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}

Class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        APIsRuler.oneRecipeFound = { result in // 3
            print(result)
        }
    }
}
```

1. `oneRecipeFound` starts out life empty: it is `nil`.
2. In FirstVC, the cell is clicked. We call `oneRecipeFound`. It is still `nil`, so nothing happens.
3. In SecondVC, we set the value of `oneRecipeFound`. Now it has a value, but the call has already happened.

So unless you have a time machine in your pocket, so that you can reverse that order of events somehow, the strategy you’ve outlined is doomed to failure. Of course, if you call `oneRecipeFound` *after* setting it, it will work. For example:

```
Class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        APIsRuler.oneRecipeFound = { result in
            print(result)
        }
        APIsRuler.oneRecipeFound?(oneRecipe) // prints
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, however, I cannot recommend using class-level globals like this. It feels like an antipattern. `oneRecipeFound` should probably be an instance property of FirstVC.